# Debian install of PostGIS extension is installing X packages

Tags: linux, postgresql, apt, debian-stretch, postgis

I'm trying to install PostGIS on a Debian server running Stretch. I installed PostgreSQL on it without any problems, but when I try to install the package `postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3`, the latest available, apt-get tries to install truckload of X and unrelated packages:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                
Building dependency tree                                                                                                     
Reading state information... Done                                                                                            
The following additional packages will be installed:                                                                         
  fontconfig libasound2 libasound2-data libass5 libasyncns0 libaudio2 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data                  
  libavahi-common3 libavc1394-0 libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libbluray1  
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0                    
  libboost-serialization1.62.0 libboost-system1.62.0 libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-thread1.62.0 libboost-timer1.62.0          
  libbs2b0 libcaca0 libcairo2 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcgal12 libchromaprint1 libcoin80v5 libcroco3      
  libcrystalhd3 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3 libdc1394-22 libdrm2 libebur128-1 libegl1-mesa libfaad2 libfftw3-double3     
  libflac8 libflite1 libfribidi0 libgbm1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa            
  libglib2.0-0 libgme0 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgraphite2-3 libgsm1 libharfbuzz0b libice6 libiec61883-0 libiso9660-8       
  libjack-jackd2-0 libldb1 liblwgeom-2.3-0 libmad0 libmng1 libmodplug1 libmp3lame0 libmpcdec6 libmpg123-0 libnuma1 libogg0   
  libopenal-data libopenal1 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenmpt0 libopenscenegraph100v5 libopenthreads20   
  libopus0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpixman-1-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpostproc54    
  libpulse0 libpython2.7 libqt4-opengl libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libraw1394-11 librsvg2-2 librubberband2 libsamplerate0           
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsfcgal1 libshine3 libsm6 libsmbclient libsnappy1v5 libsndfile1 libsndio6.1 libsodium18 libsoxr0           
  libspeex1 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample2 libswscale4 libtalloc2 libtbb2 libtdb1 libtevent0 libthai-data libthai0           
  libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvdpau1            
  libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx4 libwavpack1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1-mesa    
  libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebpmux2 libwmf0.2-7 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libx264-148 libx265-95 libxau6    
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1              
  libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxine2 libxine2-bin libxine2-ffmpeg  
  libxine2-misc-plugins libxine2-plugins libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxss1 libxt6      
  libxtst6 libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxxf86vm1 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 python-talloc qtcore4-l10n samba-libs             
  shared-mime-info x11-common xkb-data
```

Any idea what's going on here? I don't want any X related packages on my server and I'm trying to avoid compiling by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `libsfcgal1` package from stretch-backports before installing `postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3`.

---

The culprit package is `libsfcgal1`, which depends on `libopenscenegraph100v5`.

The relevant part of the dependency chain is:

- `postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3` depends on
- `libsfcgal1` which depends on
- `libopenscenegraph100v5` which depends on
- `libav*` packages, `libqt*` packages, `libxine2`, etc.

Here is the corresponding bug report: https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/issues/136